# How do I link a C++ library with CGO and Swig?

Tags: c++, go, swig, cgo

I want to use the C++ program [xmr-stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak) in my Go program. After some research, I settled on [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate the bindings. The issue is that ld cannot find the library file. I'll just write down step by step what I did.

I created this file at `src/miner/xmrstak/xmrstak.swigcxx` along with the source code of xmr-stak:

```
 %module xmrstak
 %{
#include "xmrstak/net/jpsock.hpp"
#include "xmrstak/jconf.hpp"
#include "xmrstak/misc/executor.hpp"
 %}


%include "xmrstak/misc/executor.hpp"
```

Since Swig is supported by Go, it will automatically generate the bindings at build time. But Go still requires a package name, so I've just created `package.go`:

```
package xmrstak
```

Now, I can build this project, which results in lots of errors like:

```
/tmp/go-build176223381/gitlab.com/jgillich/autominer/miner/xmrstak/_obj/xmrstak_wrap.cxx.o: In function `executor::inst()':
./xmrstak/misc/executor.hpp:35: undefined reference to `executor::executor()'
```

To fix this, it appears I need to tell ld to link the library. I've added the following to my `package.go`:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/xmrstak/ -l${SRCDIR}/libxmr-stak-backend.a
import "C"
```

And copied the `libxmr-stak-backend.a` in the same folder. This file is obtained by building xmr-stak using `cmake . && make` and should include everything I need (for now).

My issue is that this doesn't actually work. I get the following output:

```
$ go install
# gitlab.com/jgillich/autominer/miner/xmrstak
xmrstak/misc/executor.hpp:43: Warning 507: No Go typemap defined for ex_event &&
[further warnings ommitted]
# gitlab.com/jgillich/autominer/miner/xmrstak
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/jgillich/go/src/gitlab.com/jgillich/autominer/miner/xmrstak/libxmr-stak-backend.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file however definitely exists:

```
$ ls
libxmr-stak-backend.a  package.go  xmrstak  xmrstak.swigcxx

$ file /home/jgillich/go/src/gitlab.com/jgillich/autominer/miner/xmrstak/libxmr-stak-backend.a
/home/jgillich/go/src/gitlab.com/jgillich/autominer/miner/xmrstak/libxmr-stak-backend.a: current ar archive
```

Did I do anything wrong here?

Comment: @user0042 Both, the `-backend` file is compiled with g++ but there's also a `libxmr-stak-c.a` file compiled as C. Running `nu` on the first shows lots of (mangled) symbols, it kinda sucks that ld doesn't give more details other than "cannot find"...

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -lxmr-stak-backend
import "C"
```

Seems like I was just using ld wrong.